# Access application setting by name

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

In application settings I have a group of settings called "Name01", "Name02" and so on.

I have a list of strings "Name01", "Name16", "NameWhatever"..

How to check if there is a setting called "NameXX" in Settings.Default ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test it like this:

```
var x = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["NameXX"];
if(x != null) {
 //....
}
```